# Why aren't the images in my HTML table aligning properly?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm currently building an email signature, a simple 4 images sectioned off in a square 2x2 `table`.

The problem I'm currently facing is I can't remove the spacing between the `td`'s at the moment.

```html
<style>
d, tr, img  { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; display: block; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }    
    
</style>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/NDz2UL.png" ></img>
        </td>
        <td>
             <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/BMSIqd.png"></img>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/VcOrDE.png" ></img>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/DlwKjq.png"></img>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, or point me in the right direction? much appreciated!

Comment: The first image you use does not have the correct size (as the others). The table makes up for the lacking dimensions by automatically adding padding.

Comment: Ah right I see! so it has to be the same in height?

Comment: your images have different sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images all have different size. I've taken the liberty to smoothly change one of them, and the result is already way better. You should align them and honer the same dimensions on all images.

```html
<style>
d, tr, img  { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; display: block; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }    
    
</style>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tBrf7Fu.png" >
        </td>
        <td>
             <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/BMSIqd.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/VcOrDE.png" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bubblei.co.uk/DlwKjq.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! will get that sorted now

Comment: Just going over some of your "great" answers there. Just a sidenote: `</img>` isn't a valid closing tag; they can safely be removed ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh! Thanks, I merely copy-pasted OP's option, I've adjusted it!

Comment: @Roberrrt You're welcome. My bad; TBH I didn't see OP's code ;-) *cheers*